# Visual Studio 2010: CopyDirectory or xcopy to copy Whole Directory

Tags: visual-studio, xcopy

I would like to copy whole directory to another directory.
xcopy and My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyDirectory only copies the "Content" of the directory.

For example: If source: C:\Users\Myfile555\ and Destination: C:\Dest\

I would want the files to be copied to C:\Dest\Myfile555

On my Visual Studio Application, I made Source and Destination Folder button.
so i could select the folder \Myfile555 as source.

and whatever I chose as destination folder(example: \Desktop), It would become \Desktop\Myfile555.

Anyone has any tips on doing so ? Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thank you everyone.

Comment: Add the source code; should be an easy fix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source codes that I've tried:

```
Dim sourcepath = TextBox1.Text
Dim destpath = TextBox2.Text
```

Btn1:

```
Shell("cmd /k xcopy """ & sourcepath & """ """ & destpath & """ /D /E /C /I /R /H /K /Y")
```

Btn2:

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyDirectory(sourcepath, destpath, True)
```

Both commands only copy the CONTENTS of the folder, but I would like to copy both the CONTENTS + the ORIGINAL folder all the files were in.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
        string[] returnR = null;
        returnR = Directory.GetFiles(textBox3.Text + @"\", "*.xls"); ///get all excel files
```

then, you just have to do the foreach loop to copy one file from returnR array to your folder

Comment: Thank you for the help but I don't think you understood the question correctly. Basically, I would like to copy the "whole" folder, including the folder it self. so if I want to copy C:\"FolderEx1" to C:\Desktop\, then it would become C:\Desktop\"FolderEx1".

I am not really trying to copy only the contents inside the folder but the contents AND the ORIGINAL folder it self.